# How to use CSRF token in cached views?

Tags: django, redis

I'm using Redis to cache views. But I can't use forms in the cached views because of the CSRF token.

How can I use forms in a cached view?

Comment: You can't really - CRSF by definition cannot be cached for multiple users.

Comment: I want to exclude CSRF token from cache.

Comment: You could cache the whole template but the forms and pull the forms via javascript on the client side via ajax.